# Tensorflow: list of index -> generate an array

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow question about building TF array given a list of indices of its elements.

Say I have an index list with tf array

`list_index_false = tf.constant([5,3])`

I would like to build size 7 `tf.array` with booleans 
where only indices `5` and `3` are `False` while others are `True` such as below:
`[True,True,True,False,True,False,True]`

I tried following:

`list_boolean=tf.fill([7],True))`

Then tried to assign `list_boolean[3]=False`, `list_boolean[5]=False`, but tensorflow doesn't let me to assign. :(

How can I do that?
Any other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) is specifically designed for usecases like this. Here is the code example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

list_index_false = tf.constant([5, 3])
list_boolean = tf.Variable(tf.fill([7], True))
list_boolean = tf.scatter_update(list_boolean, list_index_false, tf.fill(tf.shape(list_index_false), False))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(list_boolean))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can i possibly thank you! I have been in trouble for a week startin to hate Tensorflow.. You saved me.!

Comment: Glad to help :)